# Main.storyboard file not showing up in my new Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

**The new Xcode project does not have any `main.storyboard` file in the showing the project** please help with this problem.

[image: img]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/) enabled in your project, which does not use storyboards anymore.

Your layout is inside the `ContentView.swift` file.

If you do want to work the old way, with storyboards, you should uncheck 'Use SwiftUI' in the project creation screen.

[image: From RayWenderlich]
(Image is from [this article.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3715234-swiftui-getting-started) Which is a good place to get started.)

Comment: What should I do to get the main.storyboard?

Comment: Since your project is still empyt, it's easiest to start a new project. When you get to the screen in the image from my answer, uncheck the checkbox outlined in red